# Python - reduce function and | operator

Tags: python, web2py, reduce

I am looking at some Web2py code.

The variable `tokens` is some kind of a list of strings. To be more precise, it is defined as `tokens = form.vars.name.split()` where `form.vars.name` is a string.

My question deals with the following instruction :

```
query = reduce(lambda a,b:a&b,[User.first_name.contains(k)|User.last_name.contains(k) for k in tokens])
```

Here are my questions :

1. I know `lambda a,b:a&b` defines a function of `a` and `b`. What is `a&b` ?
2. Is the `contains` method of `User.first_name` specific to Web2py ? Or does it exist in standard Python ?
3. What is this `|` operator in `User.first_name.contains(k)|User.last_name.contains(k)` ?
4. What does the `reduce` function do ?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the documentation yet?

Comment: If `contains(k)` returns a boolean it can be rewritten as `query = all(User.first_name.contains(k) or User.last_name.contains(k) for k in tokens)`.

Comment: Disregard my prior comment as `contains()` does not return a boolean and the bitwise operators have been reloaded for other purposes.  See Jochen Ritzel's answer for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In Web2Py `&` and `|` **are not bitwise and/or here**, but are used to build a special object that represents a database query! They correspond to `AND` and `OR` in SQL statements
2. [contains](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#like,-startswith,-contains,-upper,-lower) is part of [Web2Pys DAL](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#The-Database-Abstraction-Layer)
3. See 1.
4. reduce is [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), a very fundamental higher order function that essentially reduces a list to a result, using the function given.

Comment: I'm torn as to whether this is a good use of operator overloading.  On the one hand it allows users to succinctly state what they want to do.  On the other, the inexperienced reader will be totally confused because operator overloading to a meaning so different that the meaning of the operator is uncommon (at least i believe it's uncommon).

Answer (score 0):

1. [Bitwise and](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).
2. I believe contains, in that context is more-or-less a mapping to `__contains__`, but it does appear in [Py3k docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/operator.html?highlight=contains#module-operator).
3. [Bitwise or](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).
4. [reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) iterates through an iterable object (param 2) and calls the passed function (param 1) on all of the elements. It returns the aggregate value.

Answer (score 0):

1. `&` is the bitwise and operator. The person writing the code almost certainly meant `and`, although for boolean values the result is the same.
2. `.contains()` is a method provided by web2py. `a.contains(b)` is more pythonically written as `b in a`.
3. `|` is the bitwise OR operator. Again, they probably meant `or`.
4. `reduce` applies the function given as the first argument to the iterable in the second argument, from left-to-right, first with the first 2 elements, then with the result of that calculation and the third element, etc.